# How to make a circular swipe?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, geometry

I'm trying to make a video similar to this one (Made in Adobe After Effects)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAV5DwR1pU8
But I don't know how to make the circle disappear than reappear with a circular swipe. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Pacman-esque clock icon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/how-to-create-a-pacman-esque-clock-icon)

Comment: Well its similar, but I want something more 2 dimensional and flat. I know thats rather strange, Blender being a 3D application.

Comment: Boolean modifiers don't work well on 2D shapes, and I'm not sure of any other way to do it that is completely smooth... You could just make a very thin cylinder and render it from the top.

Comment: Using beveled curves would work well too. Was about to write an answer but there already is an accepted answer :o)

Comment: @user2859 I tried curves, but I couldn't get a nice result.. We like lots of answers here, feel free to answer anyway :)

Comment: @user2859 having an accepted answer doesn't mean  that there aren't other valid answers to contribute. Also, the accepted answer can be changed too by the person who asked the question if there is a better one!

Comment: WOW! So many great ways! I feel bad about choosing a specific one. There all amazing answers! Thank you guys so much for all of this!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another way using **beveled curves**:

1. Add a **Bezier Circle** in Object Mode and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter **Edit Mode**.
2. With all handles selected press <kbd>V</kbd> and select **Free**.
3. Select only one handle and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to open the circle.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and choose **Cursor to Selected**.
5. Select the handle on the other side of the opening and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.
6. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, and choose **Selection to Cursor (Offset)** to move the handle to the other side.
7. Rotate the handle by 90 or 270 degress to get a circular shape (<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>$Axis</kbd> <kbd>$Degress</kbd>), then leave **Edit Mode**.
8. Add a **Path** in Object Mode. To get a closed slice, scale the Path by `.5`. Otherwise, < `.5`.
9. Select the Bezier Circle again. Under **Curve Properties - Geometry - Bevel Object** select the name of the newly added **Path** (e.g. NurbsPath).
10. To animate the slice use the **Start** and **End** values (**Geometry - Bevel Factor**).

[image]
[image]

This should be the result (animated scale of the Path, Start and End values of the Bevel Factor):

[image]

Another way could be using the **Array Modifier** together with the **Curve Modifier** to get some line effects (similar to the reference you provided).

Starting from a **Bezier Circle** and a **Plane** in the same spot, add both modifiers to the Plane. You can play with the scale of the Plane, count and offset of the Array Modifier to get different effects.

[image]

Here some examples:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10):

you can do it by adding a plane and merge the top and buttom vertex whith each other
[image]

then scale it is the depth of the circle you want and move it away from the origin point

[image]

then add a screw modifier and increase the number of steps to something like 50 and check flip if the normal is flipped
[image]

then make the angle 0 and go to frame one and press I when you are over the angle icon
[image]

then go to frame 20 and make the angle 360 and press I while you are over it
[image]

then split your windows into 2 taps and convert one into graph editor select all by A+A and press V and select vector to make the animation constant
[image]

play you animation by ctrl+A and you will see it.

Comment: Thats EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Just out of curiosity, where did you learn about this?

Comment: Is it possible you could add some more details to your answer? If the link goes down, so does the answer..

Comment: ok I make a tutorial on it now