# How to colour faces produced by a Boolean modifier

Tags: materials

I have produced an indent in a cube using a UV sphere and a Boolean modifier. The cubes white and the sphere is black. But when I try to colour the indent it colours the whole cube. Has anyone got any ideas please

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh. Same principle in 2.8, property tabs are just vertically disposed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have both materials on the Object with the boolean modifier (but of course only one of those is assigned to that mesh). Here the blue cube (the cube with the boolean modifier) has both materials: the blue and the red material. The red cube only has the red material.

[image: Both materials on blue cube, blue is assigned to mesh]
[image: The Red cube only needs the red material]

[image: Now the cut faces are red]

Comment: maybe reformulate because "Boolean Object" could be the object that cuts, actually you're talking about the "booleaned" object

Comment: Thanks moonboots! I now edited my answer to be less unclear.

Comment: one thing easier - you don't have to set material to red cube, just place red material of blue cube above (at first place) in material list. Can you add it to your answer? This Q is duplication of this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101451/add-colour-to-a-cut-meshface-in-animation?answertab=votes#tab-top but its easier to follow for me here :)