# List of vertices at intersection of two objects

Tags: python, modifiers, vertices

I am using python to form the union of two cylinders through the use of boolean modifiers as shown in the image. How can I obtain a list of the vertices at the intersection of the two objects that are created when the modifier is applied?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to join the two parts as a single mesh? Why use a boolean? Read: Creating Seamless Decal Meshes in  https://topologyguides.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just a possible way to do this (there might be a better method to do this):

First set up materials on both objects (as in my answer in the link) and apply the boolean modifier: [How to colour an indent that's been produced by a Boolean modifyer in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144686/how-to-colour-an-indent-thats-been-produced-by-a-boolean-modifyer-in-2-8/144687?noredirect=1#comment246874_144687)

Then select by each individual materials, loop through them and save those vertices that are in common for both material selections. These should be the vertices you are looking for!

Happy blending!

Comment: I think he is looking for a way to access these vertices by python